# Why logical X_L measurements for planar code seems to be non-deterministic in stim

Tags: stim

I have defined a stim circuit for distance 3 planar code in stim. Now as the vertical line is supposed to be the logical X operator, I defined the logical observable as

```
circuit.append_operation("OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE", [stim.target_rec(-1), stim.target_rec(-2), stim.target_rec(-3)], 0)
```

where the last 3 data measurements contains the last column of data qubits. Although stim outputs them as non-deterministic. What seems to be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you compare your circuit to the surface code circuit that is used in getting_started.ipynb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without the entire circuit.

The logical X observable is only deterministic if you are in the logical plus or logical minus state. My best guess at what is happening (without seeing your circuit) is that you're preparing all data qubits in the 0 state. For the logical X observable to be deterministic you need to prepare each data qubit in the plus state.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I see the problem now. Yes I prepared all the qubits in |0> state initially, that made the logical X positions non-deterministic.